# App isn't working in APN settings of portalnmms

Tags: android

My app isn't working in APN settings of portalnmms of Vodafone sim where as google, you tube are working. While hitting API, returns the retrofit error as

> "retrofit.RetrofitError: \n not found: size=165 content=....."

Comment: `\n not found`: do you pass a newline instead of a URL?

Comment: NO, but my app working fine in wi-fi and with other nertwork provider. Even in vodafone, its working when the APN settings is in www